# How to overlap cell value from one cell to next cell in datagridview in c#.net window application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want a cell value overlap in next cell value when we resize column in datagridview in c#.net application.

means we want merge two cell horizontally.

Question is - 01111 | 22222 | 3333

Answer Should be - 011112222 | 3333

Thanks IN advance.

Comment: Please improve your tags, what are you useing, WinForms / WPF / ...

Comment: we are using c#.net  in windows form

Answer (score 0):

If you work with WPF, you can get the TextBlock from your datagridtextcolumn and set the following option:

```
yourTextBlockInstance.TextTrimming = TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis;
```

Or simply try this:

```
yourColumn.ElementStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
yourColumn.ElementStyle.Setters.Add
(
    new Setter(TextBlock.TextTrimmingProperty, TextTrimming.CharacterEllipsis)
);
```

Comment: i m not using wpf im on windows form

Answer (score 0):

There is a `datagridview property` called `RowDefaultCellStyle`. The `WrapMode` is probably by default set to `not set`. Change it to `true`. Thats it.